# Rest set @Path for resource updates

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Using Jersey, what is the **RESTish** way to this, Should I create a method starting with "update" like this, or I should create a subresource (or whatever Jax-Rs thing) under accountseetings path? Or should I simply use the same method name with different verbs?

```
@GET
@Path("/accountsettings")
public Settings accountSettings() {

}

@PUT
@Path("/updateaccountsettings")
public void updateAccountSettings() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REST verbs define what you are doing and URLs define what you are doing it to.

So here a PUT to `/accountsettings` would seem to be the normal way to do it.

Calling the method `updateAccountSettings()` seems to make sense.

Comment: ok so different verbs for different purposes but using same path, thats what I tried and got error"405 HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL"

Comment: so I thought somehow it it does not see the put but only see the get, any ideas?

Comment: That's a different question; you'll need to show what you did to get that error.